# Any class document or template for a constitution?

Tags: templates

I´m looking for a template or class document for a constitution like this one: https://www.constituteproject.org/constitution/Japan_1946.pdf?lang=en. It does not have to be exact of course. I have tried looking in many templates websites and found nothing.

Do you guys have some recomendations or have used one?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: @Julian Can you please include a screenshot of the desired result in your question? This ways your posts stays helpful for future users even if the link changes or the linked sites goes down.

Comment: Welcome! Since you write that it does not have to be exact, which parts of it is it that you want to obtain and that you have problems to get?

Comment: The size of the header indicates that the left column use paracol rather than marginpar.  The appearance of the chapters is closest to report.cls, but you may need to adjust the gaps.

Comment: Too open questions hardly can obtain good concrete answers. Suggestion: make a small example of Constitution  in a standard book class (no a real one, one for Lilliput just forbidding the incoming to the isle of people of Blefuscu and giants, for instance), and try to adapt to your needs (margins, font types, etc.) as far as possible, then post the example and ask only about one of the issues with that example. Questions of the type "How to obtain A, B, D and E?" are not advisable either.